# npm install returning error [trying to install butter-project]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, electron

I'm trying to install a project from GitHub and followed the installation instructions. When I run npm install in the project directory it's returning the error results below:

```html
> electron-prebuilt@0.33.6 postinstall /home/black-swan/project/butter-desktop-angular/node_modules/electron-prebuilt
> node install.js

Downloading electron-v0.33.6-linux-x64.zip
[============================================>] 100.0% of 36.63 MB (448.08 kB/s)

/home/black-swan/project/butter-desktop-angular/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/install.js:15
  throw err
        ^
Error: EACCES, rename '/tmp/electron-tmp-download-14704-1445821710129/electron-v0.33.6-linux-x64.zip'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/black-swan/project/butter-desktop-angular/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Does anybody know the issue? why this would happen.
  ->npm-debug.log

```html
177 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/read-torrent
178 silly lockFile 8232b83d--github-com-Cuevana-node-tracker git://github.com/Cuevana/node-tracker
179 silly lockFile 8232b83d--github-com-Cuevana-node-tracker git://github.com/Cuevana/node-tracker
180 verbose about to build /home/black-swan/project/butter-desktop-angular/node_modules/torrent-health
181 info /home/black-swan/project/butter-desktop-angular/node_modules/torrent-health unbuild
182 info preuninstall torrent-health@0.0.6
183 info uninstall torrent-health@0.0.6
184 verbose true,/home/black-swan/project/butter-desktop-angular/node_modules,/home/black-swan/project/butter-desktop-angular/node_modules unbuild torrent-health@0.0.6
185 info postuninstall torrent-health@0.0.6
186 error Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/black-swan/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-Cuevana-node-tracker-8232b83d'
186 error  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/black-swan/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-Cuevana-node-tracker-8232b83d']
186 error   errno: 3,
186 error   code: 'EACCES',
186 error   path: '/home/black-swan/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-Cuevana-node-tracker-8232b83d',
186 error   parent: 'torrent-health' }
187 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
188 error System Linux 3.14.1-031401-generic
189 error command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
190 error cwd /home/black-swan/project/butter-desktop-angular
191 error node -v v0.10.28
192 error npm -v 1.4.9
193 error path /home/black-swan/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-Cuevana-node-tracker-8232b83d
194 error code EACCES
195 error errno 3
196 error stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/black-swan/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-Cuevana-node-tracker-8232b83d'
197 verbose exit [ 3, true ]
```

Comment: check permissions or group name of folder /home/black-swan/.npm

Comment: did you try to run it as _sudo_?

Comment: yeah i run it ad `sudo` and it seems to didn't work either